# Is it possible to compare two characters in Processing?

Tags: string, char, compare, character, processing

I am a novice programmer and I am trying to compare two characters from different strings, such that I can give an arbitrary index from each string and check to see if they match. From the processing website it seems that you can compare two strings, which I have done, but when I try to do so with characters it seems that the arguments (char,char) are not applicable. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [String](http://processing.org/reference/String.html)'s [charAt()](http://processing.org/reference/String_charAt_.html) method/function to get character from each string at the desired index, then simply compare:

```
String s1 = ":)";
String s2 = ";)";

void setup(){
  println(CompareCharAt(s1,s2,0));
  println(CompareCharAt(s1,s2,1));
}

boolean CompareCharAt(String str1,String str2,int index){
  return s1.charAt(index) == s2.charAt(index);
}
```

**Note** that when you're comparing strings `==` doesn't help, you need to use String's [equal()](http://processing.org/reference/String_equals_.html)

```
String s1 = ":)";
String s2 = ";)";

println(s1.equals(s2));
println(s1.equals(":)"));
```

Also, if data comes from external sources, it's usually a good idea to compare both strings at using the same case:

```
println("MyString".equals("myString"));
println("MyString".toLowerCase().equals("myString".toLowerCase()));
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can pass the argument after converting(typecasting) the char to string.

(string(char),string(char))

Comment: thanks, I just checked the datatype conversion instructions on Processing and tried what you suggested. It gives this error: the function string(char) does not exist

Comment: hi thanks, I used: Character.toString('CharX') which seems to have done the trick...

Answer (score 0):

Yep. Just use == as it gets interpreted as a char datatype. 
This is assuming you've split the char from the String...

```
char a = 'a';
char b = 'a';
if(a == b) {
 // etc
}
```

As mentioned above, use .equals() for String comparison.

```
String a = "a";
String b = "a";
if(a.equals(b)) {
 // etc
}
```

Also, the proper way to cast a char as a String is str() not string()